# which domain does this Möbius map to $\Re(w) > 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation, mobius-inversion

Given the following Möbius:
$$ w = T(z) = \frac{1+z}{1-z} $$
How could I find the domain of $Z$ which $T$ maps to $\{\Re(w)>0\} $?

I tried to inverse $T$ and got:
$$ z = T^{-1}=\frac{w-1}{w+1} $$

Then I tried to see where the reversed Möbius maps the imaginary axis and got:
$$ T^{-1}(i)=-\sqrt{2}i $$
$$ T^{-1}(0)=-1 $$
$$ T^{-1}(-i)=\sqrt{2} $$

But then I could not conclude anything!
How could I find out the mapped domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T(z)=\frac {(1+z)(1-\overline {z})} {|1-z|^{2}}$ so the real part of $T(z)$ is $\frac {1-|z|^{2}} {|1-z|^{2}}$. This is positive iff $|z| <1$ so the answer is $\{z: |z|<1\}$.